# import csv file to google sheets via python

Tags: python, csv, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to setup a Python script that will automatically take a rather large csv file and upload it to a Google Sheet overwriting all the data on the current sheet.

for example lets say a new file comes out everyday of data and it is currently around 13,000 rows and goes to column ah.  I want to have my pi read that csv file that is already on the pi and overwrite the cells that are already on the google sheet from the previous day.

any advice will be greatly appreciated

Comment: not that it helps, but your 'import to' is called ''export'

Comment: Review the Sheets REST API. This is too broad currently as you have no script and no specific issue.